# How to archive (using Zip) into multiple output files

Tags: java, android, archive, zip

In Android I want to pack some files into Zip archive (using `java.util.zip`). But I have a limit for output file size - so is there a possibility to pack them into multiple, fixed-size files?

Comment: I think Zip format does not support such feature by itself, there is Rar format which supports it.

Comment: but it's not available in Android API, right?

Comment: yes, it's not available, but may could be implemented by yourself.

Comment: @yrajabi of course I could. But why bother if it's already there ;) well, in the end it's not, but at least I know about it.

Comment: If your zip archive would be used later only by yourself, then you can easily use a custom solution like what PrimosK has said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you do it like this:

Let's say, that you know (aproximately) the compress ratio of your files... You take first **few files** that doesn't exceed for example 2MB. If compress ratio is 50% you'll get 1MB file at the end. You repeat the process untill you zip all the files...

Regarding **one big text file** I would suggest this. Read the file and write it into two/three/four seperate files. You can do this with `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`... ZIP each of parts.. After unziping, glue them together again with help of `File(Input/Output)Stream`.

Comment: there will probably be a number of small text files - and here it would work. But there will also be a big, singular file - and there is no other possibility than to split it on parts.

Comment: What about splitting a big file before you ZIP it? And after unzipping glue it toggether again.

Comment: sure, but how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

We had a need to do something similar recently (not on Android but the principle is the same).  We came up with a [MultiFileOutputStream](http://gate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gate/mimir/trunk/mimir-cloud/src/java/gate/mimir/util/MultiFileOutputStream.java?view=markup) which writes to a series of fixed-size "chunks" and a corresponding [input stream](http://gate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gate/mimir/trunk/mimir-cloud/archive-unpacker/src/gate/mimir/util/MultiFileInputStream.java?view=markup) that reassembles the chunks into one stream again.  We layer a [commons-compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) TAR stream on top of the multi-file stream but you could equally well use a zip stream.